# How do you send an int[] between a server and client in Java?

Tags: java

I have been trying to find a way to send an int[] from the server to the client. I have a basic multiplayer game that works over LAN. There is currently no player limit other than those imposed by Java itself. Each player has a square that they can control using WASD. In the server, I am currently using a byte[] to store all of the player positions. The problem with this is that the positions can't go past 128 or -127. However, the DataOutputStream can write byte[]s but not int[]s. I have seen that there is a writeInt() function, but this can only send a single number rather than a bunch of them in one variable. I am worried about using this because I don't want the clients to receive the integers in the wrong order and mess stuff up. So the real question is: What is the best way to send a bunch of integers between the clients and server? I would also like to keep the speed as fast as possible. I can post my current code if you need to see it.

By the way this is my first post so if I did something wrong please let me know.

Comment: Check out `ByteBuffer` and `IntBuffer`.

Comment: At this point you might find the serialization mechanism in Java interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Obtain a connection to the client. Nowdays, this is typically done by SocketChannel class in java.nio package.
2. If hou have an array of ints, use [IntBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html) class and wrap your int[] into an IntBuffer instance.
3. Give your IntBuffer object as an argument to write() method of your SocketChannel. Don't forget to open the connection first.
4. Close the socket (Since Java 7, there is a try-with block which automatically closes resources for you).